TextButton becomes bigger through margin
slightly bigger button through margin
I'm a newbie on flutter. I'm making a app with multiple buttons and I did this:
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
  child: FilledButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.all(Colors.grey)),
    child: const Text(
    "Send To Display(s)",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    ),
  ),
),
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
    child: FilledButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.all(Colors.red)),
      child: const Text(
        "Clear Displays(s)",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
   ),
),

nothing weird.
But when I changed the first button margin to margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 5),
then the second to margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 10, 10),
the first button is larger than the other one.
I run the app on 24.04 6.8.0-39 ubuntu and 127.0.6533.88 chrome. I will update this post later after trying it on android
how to do I keep the distance between these two button 10 and not 20?

You answered yourself.
fromLTRB means Left, Top, Right, Bottom. So if you do  fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 5), that means:

Left: 10
Top: 10
Right: 10
Bottom: 5

The gap is from bottom, not from the right. The second Container has gap from the left correctly.
btw I would like to recommend you to make the space with SizedBox. Like so:
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: FilledButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.all(Colors.grey),
    ),
    child: const Text(
      "Send To Display(s)",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    ),
  ),
),
const SizedBox( // SizedBox right between
  width: 8.0,
),
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: FilledButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
    ),
    child: const Text(
      "Clear Displays(s)",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    ),
  ),
)

and I'm not a big fan o margins, go for the paddings.
